# Replacing selenium rectifier diode with silicon 1N4007

Tags: amplifier, diodes, dc, tube

I want to replace this selenium diode on an old tube amplifier with a silicon equivalent. Normally, this diode would have a lower value resistor in series with it such as a 15 ohm. Instead, this one has a 15K ohm resistor, only having about 20mA of current going through it. Is it safe to say, in this case that I can simply do a swap of the selenium for a 1N4007 and not worry about adding more resistance?

From what I've read because the voltage drop of a selenium is higher about 7-10V, and the 1N4007 is only 0.7V, you would need to add a small resistor such as 100 ohm in series with it to achieve the same voltage drop and get the same voltage in the circuit as before.

Thanks

[image: Schematic diagram showing selenium diode]

Comment: Is that a single selenium disk, or is it a stack?  Each disk has a forward voltage of about 1V.

Comment: It has about 10 disks I believe, I'll have to check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can just swap it out and trim the bias to be the same as it was before. The bias has more than a 10:1 range.

The voltage drop of a selenium rectifier depends on how many plates it has.

Comment: Thanks, I think about 10 plates but I'll check. Any way to measure the voltage drop across it without powering up the amp? I want to finish replacing caps etc before I do that.

Comment: You could take it out and put about 5-7mA or so through it with a series resistor and a bench power supply.  eg. a 1K resistor and crank the supply up slowly until the voltage across the resistor is 6V or so, then measure the voltage across the rectifier.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve a voltage drop without using a high wattage series resistor if replacing a Selenium unit for higher b+ : use a 12 KV microwave oven rectifier.  They are silicon, stacked units in a very compact case.  Good for 1 amp average and some pretty high surge ratings.  The one I recently used provided about a 12 volt drop, very similar to the characteristics of the original Selenium unit.

Comment: You could also just use a regular diode in series with a zener diode.